# Compare string array values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare, equals

I'm trying to compare each value from a string array with all the values of the same array to see if they are equal (something like "wordA" equals "wordA").
This is what I have:

```
FileReader input; 

input = new FileReader("file.txt"); 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input); 

String line = reader.readLine(); 

String[] text = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+"); 

for (int A = 0; A < text.length; A++) {

    for (int B = text.length; B > 0; B++){

        if (text[A].equals(text[B])){ 

        System.out.println("Repeated Word: "+text[A]);  

        }

    } 
}
```

It's only comparing array spaces, so if A and B = 3 (for example), it will always be true, ignoring the string inside this space. So I'm getting as output all the words in the text.

Comment: Post your code as text, not an Image

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))

Comment: What's the purpose of the `replaceAll` call?

Comment: Shouldn't the second loop be `for (int B = text.length -1; B > A; B--`? And

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that nested loop should be B-- instead of B++. Wouldn't that be a never ending loop? Either way, I don't think there is a reason to iterate in opposite directions in each loop. But to each their own.

Also, there should be some sort of comparison to make sure A != B, otherwise you would be comparing the same value in the array. `if (text[A].equals(text[B]))` will at some point compare `if (text[0].equals(text[0]))`, `if (text[1].equals(text[1]))`, etc.

This would always return true at least once for each element in the array.

You need to add a comparison of `if (A != B)` to fix it.

Like so:

```
for (int A = 0; A < text.length; A++) {
  for (int B = 0; B < text.length; B++) {
    if (A != B && text[A].equals(text[B])) {
         System.out.println("Repeated word:" + text[A]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! I made some mistakes writting the post because I simplified the code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

The second for-loop is faulty, you will get an array index out of bounds.

Instead you should start from the beginning too and exclude if index is equal

```
String[] text = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "a" };
for (int a = 0; a < text.length; a++) {
  for (int b = 0; b < text.length; b++) {
    if (text[a].equals(text[b]) && a != b) {
      System.out.println("Reapeated word : " + text[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

or as was suggested in comments, start from the next element in array (in which case you don't have to check if the indices are equal)

```
String[] text = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "a" };
for (int a = 0; a < text.length; a++) {
  for (int b = a + 1; b < text.length; b++) {
    if (text[a].equals(text[b])) {
      System.out.println("Reapeated word : " + text[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your second loop is doing an unnecessary comparison. Your loop should be `for (int b = a+1; b < text.length; b++)`

Comment: Janar I would remove the first example as this does not work because you want to find duplicates and your first example will always compare a value to itself thus printing every element in the list. Just leave the second.